# Can finite non-isomorphic groups of the same order have isomorphic endomorphism monoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is related to [If $G$ and $H$ are nonisomorphic group with same order then can we say that $Aut(G)$ is not isomorphic to $Aut(H)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557846/if-g-and-h-are-nonisomorphic-group-with-same-order-then-can-we-say-that-aut) and [Can non-isomorphic abelian groups have isomorphic endomorphism rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430612/can-non-isomorphic-abelian-groups-have-isomorphic-endomorphism-rings/430896#430896?newreg=63cf9042211a4127b2c9637be9004ba4) but more general than both. The answer given in the first link says that two finite non-isomorphic groups can have isomorphic automorphism groups. The second link (apparently) gives an example of two non-isomorphic *infinite* groups with isomorphic endomorphism rings. But if $G$ and $H$ are two non-isomorphic *finite* groups of the same order, is it possible for their endomorphism monoids to be isomorphic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily.

I cannot think of a simple example right now, but there are plenty of examples of finite $p$-groups $G$ of nilpotence class $2$ such that

1. all automorphisms are central, and
2. an endomorphism that is not an automorphism maps $G$ into $Z(G)$.

Now if you take two non-isomorphic such groups $G_{1}, G_{2}$ in which the $G_{i}/Z(G_{i})$ and the $Z(G_{i})$ are elementary abelian and isomorphic, then their endomorphism monoid are isomorphic.

As a reference, see [this paper of mine](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869385900687/1-s2.0-0021869385900687-main.pdf?_tid=fb661c5c-df60-11e3-a167-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1400509518_646f94cff0a1f2a2c492c7b63e408b20) (should be freely accessible, in case please advise), particularly Section 2 and Theorem 4.3.